# About web service Json/rest api/Nsurl connection

Tags: ios, web-services, afnetworking

I am starting learning about web service, where I use one url api to get data and to display in my table view. But I saw some tutorials - in that they use **`NSURLConnection`** or **Rest API** or **AFNetworking**.

I am really confused about all type. Which one should I use in that above type. For web service which type should I use. And also I saw some doubts in SO that use synchronous or asynchronous. Thus this any another type to get data from URL?

Actually for all **web service**, which should I use to get data and display?

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(void)JsonDataParsing
 {


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:url parameters:params
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
              //!!! here is answer (parsed from mapped JSON: {"result":"STRING"}) ->
              NSString *res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"result"]];
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              //....
          }
     ];

 }
```

Comment: Actually What that `dictfeed` And `arrEntry` ... You convert json data to mutableDictionary. And why that "feed"

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest` deprecated into `iOS9`.

Comment: this is about `nsurl`. Then we should not use `Afnetworking`, `rest kit` and all or what??. Then for what type of `web service` you will use `AFNetworking` and `rest kit`...

Comment: feed is key of json Responce. and feed type is dictionary so in dictfeed getting all feeds .

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, AFNetworking and NSURLConnection are used on Mobile Side. 
Rest API is not from mobile side. Rest API you implemented on server side which handle CRUD operations like GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Third party libraries are there to ease our work. And [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is very popular and trustworthy library.

AFNetworking makes asynchronous network requests. To read more about it, visit [Introduction to AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking).

AFNetworking does everything NSURLConnection can. Using it now will save you a lot of time writing boilerplate code!

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` is apple API use to manage network operation like download and upload, `AFNetworking` is the framework that use those 2 API and added multithreading/error handling/network reachability....to make your life easier, RESTful is the architecture for client-server connecting, u can implement it in your serverside to return things back to your clientside in easy to use model (JSON).

`synchronous` mean u wait for it to complete to do anything else, `asynchronous` means u just start it but don't need to wait for it, like u do a request to server and user still can interact with your UI at the same time, so its advised that use `asynchronous task` to request to server then only update the UI in `synchronous`

hope my explain is easy to understand and correct :)

Comment: Yes i am clear now about AFNetworking and Sunchronous and asynchronous... But Rest is client server connecting means i am confused

Comment: i am using one url to get,post data and to display that in table view. for that Nsurlconection and Afnetworking to use....But can i use that RESTFul for this same purpose like to get data and display that in table view

Comment: Its all depends on the server, if that server is built to handle RESTful then u can have it to request anything, because RESTful have some already URL structure like GET, POST,...each served its purpose like request to get data or upload data to server....API mean the server side code to handle those URL and execute it

Comment: U dont really need to understand much of those to use thought, except when u'r creating everything yourself, basically its just the URL request structures (a link with header and body) and `AFNetworking ` or `NSURLSession ` is already implements it for easy creating those request

Answer (score 1):

> **NSURLConnection**

This lets you to load the content of `URL` by providing the `URL` request object. By using `NSURLConnection` you can load URL requests both **asynchronously** using a callback block and **synchronously**. See this example

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     // ...
 }];
```

For more you can go to [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html)

> **AFNetworking**

This is third party library built on the top of **Foundation URL Loading**.
This is very easy to install through pods and handy to use. See below example like how I am using the same in my app

```
-(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)manager
{
    if (!_manager)
    {
        _manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        _manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        _manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    }   
    return _manager;
}
```

Above we are initializing the instance of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager`

```
[self.manager POST:@"http://example.com" parameters:parameters

               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSError *error;
         NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
         // return response dictionary in success block
     }

               failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         // return error in failure block
     }]
```

Above method will load data asynchronously and remaining is self explanatory. But if you want to block the user interface like a synchronous request than use `[operation waitUntilFinished]` which is an anti-pattern. Here `operation` is a instance of `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Comment: @joseph **REST** is just a type of **API** like **SOAP**

Comment: should i use REST to get data and post data in my table view

Comment: Yeah for sure **REST** is very fast responsive type API.